# Get most recent date IF that date is before given date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called 'Days' set up like this (The Day column is type DateTime):

```
User_ID | Day
----------------------------------
39      | 2010-05-16 00:00:00.000
39      | 2009-05-16 00:00:00.000
40      | 2008-06-12 00:00:00.000
40      | 2008-10-07 00:00:00.000
41      | 2010-04-10 00:00:00.000
41      | 2010-03-02 00:00:00.000
42      | 2010-08-12 00:00:00.000
42      | 2011-09-15 00:00:00.000
```

What I'm trying to do is, when given a User_ID and a certain date, get the most recent "Day" IF and only IF that user does not have any "Day" equal to or after the given date.

For example, given `User_ID = 39` and `date = 2010-05-15`, nothing should be returned since one of the "Day" dates listed for `User_ID = 39` is after the given date `2010-05-15`. However, if `User_ID = 40`, it would return `2008-10-07`, since that is the most recent date that is NOT equal to OR after the given date `2010-05-15`.

I have this so far, but I have no clue how to add in the "if" clause. Below just returns the most recent date for the given user.

```
 SELECT MAX(Day) from Days WHERE User_ID = 39
```

After that it would be something like `if MAX(Day) < 2010-05-15`

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: add condition to your where clause where day <= givendate and apply max of date

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX([Day]) as TheDay FROM Days
WHERE User_ID = 39
  AND [Day] < '20100515'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Days WHERE User_ID = 39 AND [DAY] >= '20100515')
```

With CTE:

```
with CTE(User_ID, [Day]) as
(
    SELECT * FROM Days WHERE User_ID = 39
)
SELECT MAX([Day]) as TheDay FROM CTE
WHERE [Day] < '20100515'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE [DAY] >= '20100515')
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

**General Logic:** Generate a set of data having the max date for each user then limit that set to be only those records with dates less than date desired and for desired user.

One approach is to use an inline view and a self join.  In my example I called the inline view B.  in it I get max date and user from days.

Then, join back to days based on user and day listed to only return a user's max day.  We then limit to user and max date *desired*.  If max date is less than date desired then a record would be returned.  If max date is >= date provided it will return no record for the user.

```
SELECT d.day
FROM days d
INNER join (SELECT user_ID, max(date) mdate 
            FROM days 
            GROUP BY user_ID) B
 on d.user_ID = b.user_ID
and b.mdate = d.day
WHERE d.day < 'inputdate'
 and d.user_ID = 'userid'
```

or perhaps more simply...

Since you want the max date for each user, but only if their date is not greater than a desired dates... simply return the max date for any user, then eliminate those > desired date for desired user.

```
SELECT mdate 
FROM (SELECT user_ID, max(date) mdate 
                FROM days 
                GROUP BY user_ID) B
WHERE mdate <= 'datedesired'
and user_ID = 'user_ID_Desired'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add day condition in WHERE Clause

```
SELECT MAX(Day) from Days WHERE User_ID = 39 AND Day < yourInputDate
```

Comment: Edit: Sorry, thought it was working but didn't after testing more dates

Comment: Really?? How is this condition met? `IF and only IF that user does not have any "Day" equal to or after the given date.`

Comment: Your query doesn't satisfy the OP example.

Comment: @pfinferno, what is missing or not working? can you give some more data points?

Comment: It's giving me the most recent date before the given date. But like xQbert said above, it should only give me the most recent date before that given date IF and only IF the most recent date is before the given date.

Comment: @pfinferno i don't know what you mean by, unless I see some data points

Comment: @techspider `given User_ID = 39 and date = 2010-05-15, nothing should be returned since one of the "Day" dates listed for User_ID = 39`  so 2010-05-16 for user_ID 39 is after date desired.  Yet your query would return `2009-05-16` when no date should be.  This fails to meet the requirement `IF and only IF that user does not have any "Day" equal to or after the given date.`

Comment: No problem.  We are all learning; and interpreting questions is quite hard sometimes.